how do I make a html file automatically load a file instead of manually opening the file each time
I am trying to have a gb emulator automatically load a game like seen on this https://yexex2.github.io/gameboy/launcher.html#kirbymirror
I am pretty sure that the # can be used but i have no idea how
I want to be able to have a list of games that you can click on and it will open the emulator and automatically load the game too

The part after (and including) the octothorpe (the URL's fragment identifier, to be precise) is available as location.hash.
You can read that during your page's load, and if present, try to load the ROM, or do whatever you like. However, you can't automatically load a file from the user's computer, if that's what you mean – of course, if you have previously had the user select the file, you could have stored it in e.g. IndexedDB, a per-page FileSystem, etc., and read it by name from there.
